# Is there an analog to `return` when importing a module in python?

Tags: python, return, python-import

#### Disclaimer

**Im aware, I could simply write the code indented** under `if __name__ == '__main__` **or put it in a function**. However, that would add an unnecessary indentation level. I'm also aware this would be bad style and I should write a proper module. I was just wondering. An entry-point for use with `setuptools` is, of course, even better and people should not be lazy and use these with virtualenv for testing. I'm asking this question for the purely academic knowledge of 'is there a command to finish importing a file early'.

---

## Actual question

**One can return functions early to prevent the rest of the function code from executing.** This has the benefit of saving an indentation level. Example:

```
def my_func(arg):
    print arg
    if arg == 'barrier':
        return
    print 'arg is not barrier'
    # ...
    # alot more nested stuff that
    # will not be executed if arg='barrier'
```

Saves an indentation level, when compared to:

```
def my_func(arg):
    print arg
    if arg == 'barrier':
        return
    else:
        print 'arg is not barrier'
        # ...
        # alot more nested stuff that
        # is one indentation level deeper :-(
```

**Is it possible to do something similar, when importing a module, so that the rest of the code is not imported?** 
For example in the module file:

```
# !/usr/bin/python
# I'm a module and a script. My name is 'my_module.py'.
# I define a few functions for general use, and can be run standalone.

def my_func1(arg):
    # ... some code stuff ...
    pass

def my_func2(gra):
    # ... some other useful stuff ...
    pass

if __name__ != '__main__':
    importreturn   # Statement I'm looking for that stops importing
    # `exit(0)` here would exit the interpreter.

print 'I am only printed when running standalone, not when I'm imported!'
# ... stuff only run when this file is executed by itself ...
```

So that I don't see *"I am only printed when running standalone, not when I'm imported!"*, when I do:

```
import my_module.py
my_func2('foobar')
```

Comment: *however, that would add an unnecessary indentation level* - it if requires adding an indentation level, in what way is it "unnecessary" ?

Comment: In the sense that with functions you can get away without it by returning the function. I was just wondering if there was a way of 'returning', read 'terminating' the import of a file prematurely. Admittedly my example is not a good use case for this, but there could be others. Read it as a 'what if'-type of question.

Comment: Put the optional code in another module, and from x import * it.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: I like that, it combines readability and correctness. I'd still be interested in the question, if there is a statement in python that stops importing of a module midway.

Comment: The answer to that is "No", I'm quite sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no statement for that in Python.

The closest thing to what you want is to raise an exception and doing your import inside a try/except block. The code after the raise statement won't be executed.

To really implement an statement like that you will need a custom import handler that does some pre-processing, and/or a custom compiler. It might be an interesting challenge if you want to learn about Python internals, but not something you should use in real applications.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to avoid the indentation, the indentation concisely makes it clear what you intend the code to do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "I am only printed when running standalone, not when I'm imported!"
else:
    print "I am only printed when importing"
```

---

If you want you could wrap this in a function?

```
def main():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print "I am only printed when running standalone, not when I'm imported!"
        return
    print "I am only printed when importing"

main()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the attention. I'm aware I could do it that way, and generally I want to have the indentation for style reasons. Except this time I don't. I think I mentioned that in my question. The function would have the 'extra' indentation as well.